# Gatsby: How to close previously opened item if new one is selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page where are list items with option to click on each of them and open info box. When I click on one, info box is being opened, but when I click on another, the previously one stays there instead of closing it. How can I make it work, so when I click on new, the previously opened closes? My code here?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../../styles/styles.scss";
import InfoIcon from "../../images/icons/info.svg";
import InfoBox from "../info/InfoBox";

const Step = ({ title, description }) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const openInfo = () => {
        setShow(true);
    };

    const closeInfo = () => {
        setShow(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <li>
                <div className="list-item" onClick={openInfo}>
                    <div className="list-item-content">
                        <h3>{title}</h3>
                        <InfoIcon className="info-icon" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            {show && (
                <InfoBox
                    title={title}
                    description={description}
                    closeInfo={closeInfo}
                />
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default Step;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- move `const [show, setShow] = useState(false);` to the parent component.
- Instead of a `boolean` you could store the `title` of the infoBox, initialising it to `null` . `[openedInfo, setOpenedInfo] = useState(null);`
- the `Step` component will have 2 other props: `setOpenedInfo` and `openedInfo`
- `openInfo` will be  `const openInfo = () => setOpenedInfo(title)`
- `closeInfo` will be `const closeInfo = () => setOpenedInfo(null)`
- You will show the `infoBox` if `openedStep === title`

This way you will always have only one infoBox open.

I'm assuming that the `title` is a `string` and is unique. You can substitute `title` with any other (unique) value related to the `Step` component.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "../../styles/styles.scss";
    import InfoIcon from "../../images/icons/info.svg";
    import InfoBox from "../info/InfoBox";
    
    const ParentComponent = () => {
    [openedInfo, setOpenedInfo] = useState(null);
    return data.map(({title,description})=><Step title={title} description={description} setOpenedInfo={setOpenedInfo} openedInfo={openedInfo}/>)
    }

    const Step = ({ title, description, setOpenedInfo, openedInfo }) => {
    
        const openInfo = () => {
            setOpenedInfo(title); //better use an id if available
        };
    
        const closeInfo = () => {
            setOpenedInfo(null);
        };
    
        return (
            <>
                <li>
                    <div className="list-item" onClick={openInfo}>
                        <div className="list-item-content">
                            <h3>{title}</h3>
                            <InfoIcon className="info-icon" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
    
                {openedInfo === title && (
                    <InfoBox
                        title={title}
                        description={description}
                        closeInfo={closeInfo}
                    />
                )}
            </>
        );
    };
    
    export default Step;
```

Comment: Can't get it to work with your approach. Can you please edit the component with your example?

Comment: Thanks! Now it is more clear to me how it works. But now I get this error: TypeError: setOpenedInfo is not a function

Comment: I added InfoBox component into the parent component and it works now. Thanks a lot!!!